# jquery mobile fullcalendar prev next icon

Tags: jquery-ui, fullcalendar, imagebutton

When using the jquery fullcalendar plugin (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) with jquery mobile, the prev and next month button icons only show the arrow-up background image, which is the very first icon on the long 256 by 240 .png image file. When I refresh the page in Firefox, the correct arrow east and west show up, yet I lose all other styles including background, themes, etc. Refresh does not work in IE.

I searched high and low for an answer to this relatively minor issue. Here I believe may be the causes:

1. jquery ui and jquery mobile conflict (order of .js and .css files) --I tried all orders to no avail.

2. calling fullcalendar theme on mobile page (inside of page instead of head tags)

3. transition issue from home to specific mobile page

4. pixel size of ui-icon css class (should it be larger than 16px by 16px for mobile?)

5. need of a custom override of jquery ui using the $(document).ready() function.

Please see my included files head code below:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../fullcalendar/demos/cupertino/thememobile.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' media='print'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='../fullcalendar/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../fullcalendar/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar/calendareventsmobile.js'></script>
```

Any answer or brainstorming of answers will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the FullCalendar with the `theme` option set to `true`? This forces it to use the jQuery UI theme instead of the fullCalendar theme. Maybe the CSS conflicts might go away then.

Comment: I did try theme set to true with no luck. The arrow-up still shows on button icon images.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation...

A hash must be supplied that maps button names (from the header) to icon strings. The icon strings determine the CSS class that will be used on the button. For example, the string 'circle-triangle-w' will result in the class 'ui-icon-triangle-w'.

I was looking to use ui-icon-carat-1-w and ui-icon-carat-1-e.  I found firebug to be very helpful in determining the correct hash value to use to get the proper mapping.

This is an example of what I needed to use.

```
    buttonIcons: {
        prev: 'carat-1-w',
        next: 'carat-1-e'
    },
```