# Unable to use glyphicon in next&prev buttons of fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm trying to change a style of next, previous buttons of fullcalendar by using a glyphicon.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      buttonText : {
          prev : '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></i>',
          next : '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></i>'
      }
  });
});
```

It's not working. It's shown like this:

[image: glyphicon with fullcalendar]

And here is a rendered html code,
[image: rendered html code]

I didn't know what was wrong.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe prev and next are only expected text. And even if there are html tags, they are considered as text.
Did you tried to add these icon in javascript after the creation of the calendar?

Like:

```
...
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  buttonText : {
      prev : '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></i>',
      next : '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></i>'
  }
});
$(".fc-prev-button").append('<i class="glyphicon"...</i>')
...
```

Comment: Guys i am also have this exact issue ..i couldn't understood how to apply your answer...Thanks for your help

Comment: You have to append your glyphicons to the buttons after calling 'fullCalandar'. I don't know how to better explain... Look at my code, you have to do the same.

Comment: thk u for your immediate replay Powkachu, i applied your answer to 'react-fullcalendar ' that why i asked doubt.I found the solution we can directly apply any changes by using only $(".fc-prev-button").append('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"</i>')

Comment: Yes, you just need to append icons at buttons of existing calendar. I'm glad your resolved your problem

Answer (score 2):

That seems to set the text content of the button, while you want to use a custom css class to display a custom icon.

Have you tried using [`buttonsIcons`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/buttonIcons/) instead?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    buttonsIcons : {
       prev: 'left-single-arrow',
       next: 'right-single-arrow',
    }
});
```

I'm not completely sure that you can use custom named css classes, [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790660/jquery-mobile-fullcalendar-prev-next-icon) [posts](http://wp-event-organiser.com/forums/topic/prev-and-next-button-missing-on-full-calendar/) seem to hint to the fact that it could not be that easy.

Comment: what is the button icon for Calendar ?